# In multiple regression, when can ordinal IVs be treated as continuous?

Tags: multiple-regression, ordinal-data

I am conducting a multiple regression to see if my IVs can predict my DVs.

I have 10 IVs that are measured on either dichotomous scale (gender, ethnicity, if they have had trauma training), 2 nominal variables (Role and type of service (low, medium, high, low and medium) and then the rest are ordinal variables (age, qualification, length of employment, supervision frequency, and supervision satisfaction).

I have transformed Role and Type of Service IVs into dummy variables.

I am not sure whether I need to transform my ordinal variables into dummy variables, or if these can be entered into the regression model as usual, and be treated as continous?

Any help will be greatly appreciated as I am struggling to find clear answers to this

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why are you calling age and length of employment "ordinal" variables? Those would seem to be fundamentally continuous.

Comment: I am measuring age in categories, so 18-24, 25-34, 35-44, 45-54 and 55-64, and then length of employment over 3 months but less than 6, over 6 months but less than 12, over 1 year but less than 3 years, over 3 years but less than 5 years and so on

Comment: Why not use the exact measurements? Certainly you believe that a 24-year old is older than an 18-year old and that the difference between an 24-year old and a 25-year old is less than the difference between a 25-year-old and a 34-year-old.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Dave. I understand what you are saying. However I have already collected my data using these categorical options.

Comment: I get that there is some amount of categorization with the full year (18 years old and 18 years, 364 days are not the same age but get recorded as 18), but what was your rationale for binning the year-ages and binning them in those particular ranges?

Comment: Are you saying that you intentially only asked respondents for their age groups ? Is that due to privacy or similar concerns ? It's a very bad idea, statistically (but I realise there are other concerns with data collection). It means that you treat the following 2 pairs of participants the same: 1st, a pair with 18.0 and 34.99, and 2nd a pair with 24.99 and 25.0, the 2nd are clearly the same ages to within a few days, while with the first pair one is ~double the age of the other. It also means that, taking the first pair, athough they are the same age, you will treat them very differently.

Comment: Thanks for your comment Robert. Yes this was to do with ethics. I understand now that I should have done it differently.

Comment: Harrell does talk in *Regression Modeling Strategies* about the tradeoff between binning variables like this versus having missing data (or, in your case, perhaps no data at all).

Comment: Thanks for this. I am new to statistics to do not quite understand fully. Is it acceptable to transform this into dummy variables?

Answer (score 3):

Draw the graphs using each model, overlaid on the same set of axes.  If the categorical graph is close to the continuous, then use the continuous model for simplicity. If there is a gross deviation from linearity, use the categorical model.  The same comment applies to other, nonlinear functions of a continuous variable, such as a quadratic, but start simple, using a linear function. Set all other IVs to a constant like mean or mode in such graphs.

Here is an example., from Chapter 10 of "[Understanding Regression Analysis
A Conditional Distribution Approach](https://www.routledge.com/Understanding-Regression-Analysis-A-Conditional-Distribution-Approach/Westfall-Arias/p/book/9780367458522)."

[image]